# What service automatically mounts the partitions on the external drives?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

What service automatically mounts the partitions on the external drives?

How to configure it?

I want to automount partitions on external media with different UUIDs with different parameters.

This is a continuation of the unresolved issue [Why on exFAT partition all files have the attribute "executable" and how to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991000/why-on-exfat-partition-all-files-have-the-attribute-executable-and-how-to-fix)

Comment: systemd does the mounts for 16.04, which reads from `/etc/fstab` ; type `man systemd.mount` for more detail inc. on fstab (file.system.table)

Answer (score 0):

Automatically mounting of external (USB) disks is usually done by the script `/usr/share/usbmount/usbmount`, which is called by `udevd` when an external disk is attached (controlled by the rules in `/lib/udev/rules.d/usbmount`).

`usbmount` by default first looks in `/etc/fstab`, if it can find an entry corresponding to the device name or UUID of the attached device. So, one simple solution might be to add an entry in `/etc/fstab` with the UUID of the filesystem, the mountpoint and the options wanted. Don't forget to add option `nofail`to the line, as otherwise without the disk attached the boot process will hang. Example:

```
UUID=9325-22B3  /mnt/tmp    vfat    defaults,nofail 0   0
```

Instead of `defaults` you may add the parameters you want to.

Unfortunately the `usbmount` script does not react on filesystem labels; I made changes for myself to achieve that, but that does only work with labels of specific kind.

There is an additional way to modify the behaviour of `usbmount`. In the file `/etc/usbmount` you can define mountpoints, mountoptions and filesystem specific mountoptions. So, if no corresponding entry in `/etc/fstab`is found, `usbmount` looks for options matching the filesystem(s) of the disk attached. You may edit `/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf` to read (e.g.):

```
.
.
 FS_MOUNTOPTIONS="-fstype=vfat,gid=floppy,dmask=0007,fmask=0117"
.
.
```

to fit your needs for all vfat formatted partitions (change the options as you need!)

**Edit:** Maybe `usbmount` is not installed by default in ubuntu. You can install it the default way:

```
sudo aptupdate
sudo aptupgrade
sudo apt install usbmount
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fstab and mount8

This is the linux manual for mount8; http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html